# Hadoop namenode format fails on mac

Tags: macos, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop to try it out on my MacBook Pro.  I am following the steps in this article, http://dennyglee.com/2012/05/08/installing-hadoop-on-osx-lion-10-7/.  However, I am failing when I try to execute the namenode format:

hadoop namenode -format
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.2/libexec/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 20: export: `-Djava.security.krb5.kdc=”': not a valid identifier
Error: Could not find or load main class ”-Djava.security.krb5.realm=

I have the following definitions in hadoop-env.sh

export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
export HADOOP_OPTS=”-Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=”

export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS"
export HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS"

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not getting the class name from the exported variable. You can try commenting out this line from the script and try:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS=”-Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=”
```